# Terraform AWS update private S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

I have a terraform code which deploys S3, S3 policy, VPC Endpoint, VPC endpoint policy.

```
resource "aws_security_group" "S3_vpc_endpoint" {   
  name   = "s3_endpoint-sg"   
  vpc_id = data.aws_vpc.selected.id

  ingress {
    from_port        = 443
    to_port          = 443
    protocol         = "tcp"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]   }

  egress {
    from_port        = 0
    to_port          = 0
    protocol         = "-1"
    cidr_blocks      = ["0.0.0.0/0"]
    ipv6_cidr_blocks = ["::/0"]   }


  tags = var.tags

}

# Create S3 bucket 
resource "aws_s3_bucket" "databucket" {   
 bucket        = "test"   
 force_destroy = true   
 tags          = var.tags

}

# Resource to attach a bucket policy to a bucket  resource 
"aws_s3_bucket_policy" "access_through_vpc_endpoint" {   
 bucket     = aws_s3_bucket.databucket.id   
 policy     = <<EOF {    
          "Version":"2012-10-17",    
          "Id":"Policy1415115909152",    
          "Statement":[
      {
         "Sid":"Access-to-specific-VPCE-only",
         "Principal":"*",
         "Action":"s3:*",
         "Effect":"Deny",
         "Resource":[
            "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.databucket.bucket}",
            "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.databucket.bucket}/*"
         ],
         "Condition":{
            "StringNotEquals":{
               "aws:sourceVpce":"${aws_vpc_endpoint.s3.id}"
            }
         }
      }    ] } EOF   
     
      depends_on = [aws_vpc_endpoint.s3] 
      }



resource "aws_s3_bucket_ownership_controls" "databucket" {   
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.databucket.id

  rule {
    object_ownership = "BucketOwnerPreferred"   } }

resource "aws_s3_bucket_public_access_block" "databucket" {   
  bucket = aws_s3_bucket.databucket.id

  block_public_acls       = true   
  block_public_policy     = true   
  ignore_public_acls      = true   
  restrict_public_buckets = true 
}

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint" "s3" {   
  vpc_id              = data.aws_vpc.selected.id   
  service_name        = "com.amazonaws.us-east-1.s3"   
  subnet_ids          = data.aws_subnets.test_subnets.ids   
  security_group_ids  = [aws_security_group.S3_vpc_endpoint.id]   
  vpc_endpoint_type   = "Interface"   
  private_dns_enabled = true   
  tags                = var.tags }

resource "aws_vpc_endpoint_policy" "s3" {   
  vpc_endpoint_id = aws_vpc_endpoint.s3.id   
  policy = jsonencode({
    "Version" : "2012-10-17",
    "Statement" : [
      {
        "Sid" : "AccessToSpecificBucket",
        "Effect" : "Allow",
        "Principal" : "*",
        "Action" : [
          "s3:ListBucket",
          "s3:GetObject",
          "s3:PutObject"
        ],
        "Resource" : [
          "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.databucket.bucket}",
          "arn:aws:s3:::${aws_s3_bucket.databucket.bucket}/*"
        ]
      }
    ]   }) }
```

After deploying this resources I can access S3 through vpc endpoint by running this aws cli command:

- aws s3 ls s3://my-bucket/ --region us-east-1 --endpoint-url https://bucket.vpce-1a2b3c4d-5e6f.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com

To force terraform to use private endpoint I added below block to provider:

> ```
> provider "aws" {
>     region     = var.aws_region
>
>     endpoints {
>        s3      = "https://bucket.vpce-1a2b3c4d-5e6f.s3.us-east-1.vpce.amazonaws.com"
>      }
> }
> ```

I created EC2 instance in the same VPC with full access role and tried to plan terraform\terragrunt code but it took long time to plan and after gives me an error:

> │ Error: getting S3 bucket (test-63891963011907) policy:
> AccessDenied: Access Denied │     status code: 403, request id:
> 3EN8P99ZDY5R8W45, host id:
> tg+K3zhErNLy8VgN5v3KmYv8GiDw5amn8GDLZfBvpBGHowYxPWJfdvveWL7tToXU9dDKFFTU+3E=
> │  │   with aws_s3_bucket.databucket, │   on main.tf line 108, in
> resource "aws_s3_bucket" "databucket": │  108: resource
> "aws_s3_bucket" "databucket" {

Do anybody implemented such case with terraform ?
Howcan I tell terraform to use private endpoint for S3. Because by default it requests public endpoints.

Regards

Comment: Can you add the full error to the question?

Comment: @MarkoE error added

Comment: `I have a terraform code which deploys S3, S3 policy, VPC Endpoint, VPC endpoint policy.` show us

Comment: @Paolo I updated question with the resources

Comment: Try adding `s3:ListObjects` to the VPC endpoint policy

Comment: @Paolo the same error "Access Denied"

Comment: I suspect that the VPC endpoint permissions are too restrictive in that they block the terraform requests